# php mcrypt_decrypt doesn't consider null chars in data

Tags: php, encryption

php `mcrypt_decrypt` doesn't consider **null** chars in input (cipher) data. (obviously it ends on the first concurrence of a null char). How to decrypt data with null chars in it? I don't want to use `base64 encoding` and it will not work anyway since encryption will output null chars.

[Edit]
The return type is also string, so output with null chars is truncated. What is the way around this? Or is there any other encryption library I should use which operates on buffers rather than strings?

Comment: Actually i do not have this problem, only trailing \0 characters are a problem because the block cyphers will pad the original input with \0 chars to block size. Is it possible that you lost a part of the string elsewhere, e.g. when storing in a database or with a string function?

Comment: Not the trailing (padded) nulls. I have encrypted data like this: "abcd\0efgh" which is to be decrypted. See the null at position 5.

Comment: What algorithm are you using? Could you provide part of your code? I just double checked and tried to encrypt "abcd\0efgh" with code from this [example](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt), scroll down for the functions `encryptTwofish()` and `decryptTwofish()`.

Comment: Can you decrypt "abcd\0efgh"? I am using AES.

Comment: Yes, decrypting will result in the original 9 character string.

Answer (score 0):

The mcrypt library works well with data containing \0 characters. Maybe you lost a part of the string elsewhere, perhaps using a string function before printing the result.

I just double checked this example, it returns \0 characters after decrypting. You can replace MCRYPT_TWOFISH with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 if you need AES encryption.

```
/**
 * Encrypts data with the TWOFISH algorithm. The IV vector will be
 * included in the resulting binary string.
 * @param string $data Data to encrypt. Trailing \0 characters will get lost.
 * @param string $key This key will be used to encrypt the data. The key
 *   will be hashed to a binary representation before it is used.
 * @return string Returns the encrypted data in form of a binary string.
 */
public static function encryptTwofish($data, $key)
{
  if (!defined('MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM')) throw new Exception('The MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM source is required (PHP 5.3).');
  if (!defined('MCRYPT_TWOFISH')) throw new Exception('The MCRYPT_TWOFISH algorithm is required (PHP 5.3).');

  // The cbc mode is preferable over the ecb mode
  $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

  // Twofish accepts a key of 32 bytes. Because usually longer strings
  // with only readable characters are passed, we build a binary string.
  $binaryKey = hash('sha256', $key, true);

  // Create initialization vector of 16 bytes
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

  mcrypt_generic_init($td, $binaryKey, $iv);
  $encryptedData = mcrypt_generic($td, $data);
  mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
  mcrypt_module_close($td);

  // Combine iv and encrypted text
  return $iv . $encryptedData;
}

/**
 * Decrypts data, formerly encrypted with @see encryptTwofish.
 * @param string $encryptedData Binary string with encrypted data.
 * @param string $key This key will be used to decrypt the data.
 * @return string Returns the original decrypted data.
 */
public static function decryptTwofish($encryptedData, $key)
{
  if (!defined('MCRYPT_TWOFISH')) throw new Exception('The MCRYPT_TWOFISH algorithm is required (PHP 5.3).');

  $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

  // Extract initialization vector from encrypted data
  $ivSize = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
  $iv = substr($encryptedData, 0, $ivSize);
  $encryptedData = substr($encryptedData, $ivSize);

  $binaryKey = hash('sha256', $key, true);

  mcrypt_generic_init($td, $binaryKey, $iv);
  $decryptedData = mdecrypt_generic($td, $encryptedData);
  mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
  mcrypt_module_close($td);

  // Original data was padded with 0-characters to block-size
  return rtrim($decryptedData, "\0");
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is no problem with encryption. filesize() was giving me stale filesize and so it was reading incorrect number of bytes from the file. Cured with clearstatcache(). filesize caching? Great!

Comment: Also MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 uses different block size than 16 bytes. That's a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47125) in the libmcrypt.

Comment: @user1288043 - Good to hear that you solved your problem. The different block size should be no problem in practise, you can encrypt and decrypt data correctly anyway. The article only means that it does not fulfill the specification, what i cannot judge.

Comment: I am encrypting with CNG bcrypt which does not allow to change the block size. So I have to use AES 128.

Comment: @user1288043 - BCrypt is a one-way hash function, not a two-way encryption algorithm, maybe you meant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH. Why do you want to change the block size, each algorithm has its own blocksize, but this is of no consequence for you. The 16 bytes of the IV-vector mentioned in the comment, will be retrieved by `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td)` and should be correct for every algorithm, it is only a comment for MCRYPT_TWOFISH.

Comment: I am encrypting in c++ using CNG library from Microsoft. For AES encryption, it has fixed block size of 16 bytes. For decrypting in php, this block size should match.